# generate a patterned numpy matrix

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

Is it possible to generate a numpy matrix with a circular pattern of "1"s in a rest matrix of "0"s? So basically a

```
generate(ysize, xsize, ycenter, xcenter, radius)
```

Should look something like

```
[000000000]
[000000000]
[000001000]
[000011100]
[000111110]
[000011100]
[000001000]
[000000000]
```

(ok this looks stupid but on a 1000x1000 scale it would make sense)

Is there such a possibility in numpy?

Comment: Wouldn't be that hard to implement by hand.

Comment: I need it for efficiency purposes, since my "by hand" algorithms are kinda slow. i was hoping for numpy support, since it handles matrix operations way quicker than i could.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def generate(ysize, xsize, ycenter, xcenter, radius):
    x = np.arange(xsize)[None,:]
    y = np.arange(ysize)[:,None]
    return ((xcenter - x) ** 2 + (ycenter - y) ** 2 <= radius ** 2) * 1


generate(10,8,4,3,2)


array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: You can get rid of the sqrt by squaring the radius instead if you really want speed.

Answer (score 5):

A little more concisely than @eumiro's answer, but essentially the same.

```
import numpy

def generate(ysize, xsize, ycenter, xcenter, radius):
    x, y = numpy.mgrid[0:ysize,0:xsize]
    return ((x - ycenter)**2 + (y - xcenter)**2 <= radius**2) * 1
```